# ¿Problema al relacionar dos tablas de base de datos con JPA?

Tags: java, netbeans, jpa, oracle-11g

Hola mi problema es que no logro relacionar dos tablas que están de uno a muchos;simplemente al ejecutar mi código en netbeans la tabla sin foránea muestra bien el registro, pero en la que contiene llave foránea no muestra simplemente se limita a escribir en donde va el registro lo siguiente Entidad.tabla=valorderegistro. Es decir tengo dos tablas una empleados con su PK que es id_empleado y Ventas que contiene la foránea de id_empleado  el problema es que al ejecutar mi código java pasa lo siguiente lo muestro en mi Jtable y pasa lo siguiente en donde se da la conexión en la tabla ventas escribe esto Entidad.Empleados=1 lo cual en si esta bien(por que me dio el valor de la tabla principal) pero me escribió eso de Entidades.Empleados si alguien me puede ayudar mi código es el siguiente. ***Saludos y que tengan un buen día***
*Mi base de datos esta hecha en oracle 11g y la libreria es **EclipseLINK**[![
[[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MGXC.png)Esto es el resultado.][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uvJg.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uvJg.png)1g*

**Este es el codigo de empleados**

```
      @Entity
      @Table(name = "EMPLEADOS")
     @XmlRootElement
     @NamedQueries({
     @NamedQuery(name = "Empleados.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM 
     Empleados e"),
     @NamedQuery(name = "Empleados.findByIdEmpleado", query = "SELECT e FROM 
     Empleados e WHERE e.idEmpleado = :idEmpleado"),
     @NamedQuery(name = "Empleados.findByNombre", query = "SELECT e FROM 
     Empleados e WHERE e.nombre = :nombre"),
     @NamedQuery(name = "Empleados.findByCargo", query = "SELECT e FROM 
     Empleados e WHERE e.cargo = :cargo")})
      public class Empleados implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal 
       fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
         @Id
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "ID_EMPLEADO")
        private BigDecimal idEmpleado;
        @Column(name = "NOMBRE")
       private String nombre;
        @Column(name = "CARGO")
       private String cargo;
       @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idEmpleado") //idEmpleado
       private List<Ventas> ventasList;

public Empleados() {
}

public Empleados(BigDecimal idEmpleado) {
    this.idEmpleado = idEmpleado;
}

public BigDecimal getIdEmpleado() {
    return idEmpleado;
}

public void setIdEmpleado(BigDecimal idEmpleado) {
    this.idEmpleado = idEmpleado;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getCargo() {
    return cargo;
}

public void setCargo(String cargo) {
    this.cargo = cargo;
}

@XmlTransient
public List<Ventas> getVentasList() {
    return ventasList;
}

public void setVentasList(List<Ventas> ventasList) {
    this.ventasList = ventasList;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (idEmpleado != null ? idEmpleado.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Empleados)) {
        return false;
    }
    Empleados other = (Empleados) object;
    if ((this.idEmpleado == null && other.idEmpleado != null) || (this.idEmpleado != null && !this.idEmpleado.equals(other.idEmpleado))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Entidades.Empleados[ idEmpleado=" + idEmpleado + " ]";
}
```

}

**El de ventas es el siguiente:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VENTAS")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Ventas.findAll", query = "SELECT v FROM Ventas v"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Ventas.findByNumVenta", query = "SELECT v FROM Ventas v WHERE v.numVenta = :numVenta"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Ventas.findByProducto", query = "SELECT v FROM Ventas v WHERE v.producto = :producto"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Ventas.findByPrecio", query = "SELECT v FROM Ventas v WHERE v.precio = :precio")})
public class Ventas implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "NUM_VENTA")
    private BigDecimal numVenta;
    @Column(name = "PRODUCTO")
    private String producto;
    @Column(name = "PRECIO")
    private BigInteger precio;

    @ManyToOne()
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID_EMPLEADO", referencedColumnName = "ID_EMPLEADO")
    private Empleados idEmpleado;

    public Ventas() {
    }

    public Ventas(BigDecimal numVenta) {
        this.numVenta = numVenta;
    }

    public BigDecimal getNumVenta() {
        return numVenta;
    }

    public void setNumVenta(BigDecimal numVenta) {
        this.numVenta = numVenta;
    }

    public String getProducto() {
        return producto;
    }

    public void setProducto(String producto) {
        this.producto = producto;
    }

    public BigInteger getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(BigInteger precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public Empleados getIdEmpleado() {
        return idEmpleado;
    }

    public void setIdEmpleado(Empleados idEmpleado) {
        this.idEmpleado = idEmpleado;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (numVenta != null ? numVenta.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Ventas)) {
            return false;
        }
        Ventas other = (Ventas) object;
        if ((this.numVenta == null && other.numVenta != null) || (this.numVenta != null && !this.numVenta.equals(other.numVenta))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Entidades.Ventas[ numVenta=" + numVenta + " ]";
    }

}
```

**Codigo de la parte grafica**

```
public class Interfaz extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    EmpleadosJpaController cEmpleados = new EmpleadosJpaController(); // inst controlador
    VentasJpaController cVentas= new VentasJpaController();
    /**
     * Creates new form Interfaz
     */
    public Interfaz() { //todo lo que se edita aquí se ejecuta al cargar interfaz
        initComponents();
        CrearModelo1();
        CrearModelo2();
        Cargar_infoEmp();//llmar al metodo de cargar info empleado.
        Cargar_infoVentas();
    }
    //Codigo de creacion de Jtable1 tabla empleados.
public static DefaultTableModel modelo1;

    private void CrearModelo1() { 
        try {
            modelo1 = (new DefaultTableModel(
                    null, new String[]{
                        "id_empleado", "nombre",
                        "cargo"}) {
                        Class[] types = new Class[]{
                            java.lang.String.class,
                            java.lang.String.class,
                            java.lang.String.class

                        };
                        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[]{
                            false, false, false
                        };

                        @Override
                        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                            return types[columnIndex];
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
                            return canEdit[colIndex];
                        }
                    });
            jTable1.setModel(modelo1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString() + "error2");
        }
    }
    //Crear tabla de ventas
   public static DefaultTableModel modelo2;

    private void CrearModelo2() { 
        try {
            modelo2 = (new DefaultTableModel(
                    null, new String[]{
                        "Num_Venta", "Producto",
                        "Precio", "Id_empleado"}) {
                        Class[] types = new Class[]{
                            java.lang.String.class,
                            java.lang.String.class,
                            java.lang.String.class,
                            java.lang.String.class

                        };
                        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[]{
                            false, false, false, false
                        };

                        @Override
                        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                            return types[columnIndex];
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
                            return canEdit[colIndex];
                        }
                    });
            jTable2.setModel(modelo2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString() + "error2");
        }
    }
    private void Cargar_infoEmp() { //Para cargar informacion de la primera tabla empleados
        try {
            Object o[] = null;
            List<Empleados> listE = cEmpleados.findEmpleadosEntities();
            for (int i = 0; i < listE.size(); i++) {
                modelo1.addRow(o);
                modelo1.setValueAt(listE.get(i).getIdEmpleado(), i, 0);
                modelo1.setValueAt(listE.get(i).getNombre(), i, 1);
                modelo1.setValueAt(listE.get(i).getCargo(), i, 2);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    private void Cargar_infoVentas() { //Para cargar informacion de la 2da tabla ventas
        try {
            Object o[] = null;
            List<Ventas> listV = cVentas.findVentasEntities();
            for (int i = 0; i < listV.size(); i++) {
                modelo2.addRow(o);
                modelo2.setValueAt(listV.get(i).getNumVenta(), i, 0);
                modelo2.setValueAt(listV.get(i).getProducto(), i, 1);
                modelo2.setValueAt(listV.get(i).getPrecio(), i, 2);
                modelo2.setValueAt(listV.get(i).getIdEmpleado(), i, 3);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que veo yo es que cuando cargas la segunda tabla, a la hora de insertar el id del empleado, aunque el metodo al que llamas es getIdEmpleado(), ese metodo no te devuelve un ID , si no que te devuelve un objeto de la clase Empleado , entonces a la hora de mostrar el valor de ese objeto recurre al método toString() de la clase Empleado:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Entidades.Empleados[ idEmpleado=" + idEmpleado + " ]";
}
```

Es por eso que en la tabla se te muestra "Entidad.Empleados=1".
Lo que deberias de hacer en mi opinión, es que a la hora de insertar el valor del ID en la tabla, como es un objeto de la clase Empleado, llames al propio metodo que tiene ese objeto para recuperar el valor del ID.Te muestro la modificacion del código.

```
   private void Cargar_infoVentas() { //Para cargar informacion de la 2da tabla ventas
    try {
        Object o[] = null;
        List<Ventas> listV = cVentas.findVentasEntities();
        for (int i = 0; i < listV.size(); i++) {
            modelo2.addRow(o);
            modelo2.setValueAt(listV.get(i).getNumVenta(), i, 0);
            modelo2.setValueAt(listV.get(i).getProducto(), i, 1);
            modelo2.setValueAt(listV.get(i).getPrecio(), i, 2);
     /*MODIFICADO*/ modelo2.setValueAt(listV.get(i).getIdEmpleado().getIdEmpleado(), i, 3);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

En este caso , es un tanto repetitivo y puede llevar a confusion llamarle a los dos metodos getIdEmpleado, por lo que yo te recomendaria que en la clase ventas le llamases getEmpleado , porque al fin y al cabo lo que recuperas es el objeto de esa clase , y no su valor.

Comment: Muchas gracias.